# crystal reports moving a report footer above details

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

So for my report I have sums for columns and I have no idea how to either 
1. Put the report footer (where the sums are located).
2. Do I make new formulas or Field where they would go.

I'm new to CR and how stuff works with visual studio. 
Using VS2005.

I've tried making a new sum into the section above details but it was not working for me with sum.
If anyone can help that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Actually just needed this whole time just had to create a new section to the header and the sums could go there.